# Which data structure is sorted by insertion and has fast "contains" check?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that preserves the order in which the elements were inserted and offers a fast "contains" predicate. I also need iterator and random access.  Performance during insertion or deletion is not relevant. I am also willing to accept overhead in terms of memory consumption.

Background: I need to store a list of objects. The objects are instances of a class called `Neuron` and stored in a `Layer`. The `Layer` object has the following public interface:

```
class Layer {
public:
    Neuron *neuronAt(const size_t &index) const;
    NeuronIterator begin();
    NeuronIterator end();
    bool contains(const Neuron *const &neuron) const;
    void addNeuron(Neuron *const &neuron);
};
```

The `contains()` method is called quite often when the software runs, I've asserted that using callgrind. I tried to circumvent some of the calls to `contains()`, but is still a hot spot. Now I hope to optimize exactly this method.

I thought of using `std::set`, using the template argument to provide my own comparator struct. But the `Neuron` class itself does not give its position in the `Layer` away. Additionally, I'd like to have `*someNeuronIterator = anotherNeuron` to work without screwing up the order.

Another idea was to use a plain old C array. Since I do not care about the performance of adding a new `Neuron` object, I thought I could make sure that the `Neuron` objects are always stored linear in memory. But that would invalidate the pointer I pass to `addNeuron()`; at least I'd have to change it to point to the new copy I created to keep things linear aligned. Right?

Another idea was to use two data structures in the `Layer` object: A vector/list for the order, and a map/hash for lookup. But that would contradict my wish for an iterator that allowed `operator*` without a const reference, wouldn't it?

I hope somebody can hint an idea for a data structure or a concept that would satisfy my needs, or at least give me an idea for an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: `std::set` only has a bidirectional iterator not random access.

Comment: I recommend `std::map`.  It has reasonable insertion but faster lookup (contains).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews But what about the ordering constraint...?

Comment: Keeping order and fast lookup are incompatible goals.  Just wrap two collections, vector to keep order and unordered_map for lookup.

Comment: Please clarify "ordering constraint".  The `std::map` likes to have unique keys.  This "constraint" allows for faster retrieval.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `a data structure that preserves the order in which the elements were inserted`

Comment: @Technaton insertion order is one thing (easily done, just pack items on the end of a vector). But *identity* is something entirely different. Your `contains` method doesn't seem to care a lick about *where* something is; only *that* something is. You've given no indication what establishes that two `Neuron` are the "same" `Neuron`. If the external `Neuron` added to this contraption live as long as the contraption, and the origins of the `contains` oddly declared reference-to-const-pointer-to-const-Neuron are the *same as those inserted*, your container may not need to hold `Neuron`s *at all*.

Comment: @WhozCraig True, the neurons themselves have no easily-deductable identity function. That's why I'm operating with pointers here (`Neuron *`). As far as I can tell, that will help me to speed up a possible lookup; implementing an `operator ==(const Neuron &other) const` will probably come at a performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `contains` check is really where you need the fastest execution, and assuming you can be a little intrusive with the source code, the fastest way to check if a `Neuron` belongs in a layer is to simply flag it when you insert it into a layer (ex: bit flag).

You have guaranteed O(1) checks at that point to see if a `Neuron` belongs in a layer and it's also fast at the micro-level.

If there can be numerous layer objects, this can get a little trickier, as you'll need a separate bit for each potential layer a neuron can belong to unless a `Neuron` can only belong in a single layer at once. This is reasonably manageable, however, if the number of layers are relatively fixed in size.

If the latter case and a Neuron can only belong to one layer at once, then all you need is a backpointer to `Layer*`. To see if a Neuron belongs in a layer, simply see if that backpointer points to the layer object.

If a `Neuron` *can* belong to multiple layers at once, but not too many at one time, then you could store like a little array of backpointers like so:

```
struct Neuron
{
    ...
    Layer* layers[4]; // use whatever small size that usually fits the common case
    Layer* ptr;
    int num_layers;
};
```

Initialize `ptr` to point to `layers` if there are 4 or fewer layers to which the `Neuron` belongs. If there are more, allocate it on the free store. In the destructor, free the memory if `ptr != layers`. You can also optimize away `num_layers` if the common case is like 1 layer, in which case a null-terminated solution might work better. To see if a Neuron belongs to a layer, simply do a linear search through `ptr`. That's practically constant-time complexity with respect to the number of Neurons provided that they don't belong in a mass number of layers at once.

You can also use a `vector` here but you might reduce cache hits on those common case scenarios since it'll always put its contents in a separate block, even if the Neuron only belongs to like 1 or 2 layers.

This might be a bit different from what you were looking for with a general-purpose, non-intrusive data structure, but if your performance needs are really skewed towards these kinds of set operations, an intrusive solution is going to be the fastest in general. It's not quite as pretty and couples your element to the container, but hey, if you need max performance...

*Another idea was to use a plain old C array. Since I do not care about the performance of adding a new Neuron object, I thought I could make sure that the Neuron objects are always stored linear in memory. But that would invalidate the pointer I pass to addNeuron(); [...]*

Yes, but it won't invalidate *indices*. While not as convenient to use as pointers, if you're working with mass data like vertices of a mesh or particles of an emitter, it's common to use indices here to avoid the invalidation and possibly to save an extra 32-bits per entry on 64-bit systems.

### Update

Given that Neurons only exist in one Layer at a time, I'd go with the back pointer approach. Seeing if a neuron belongs to a layer becomes a simple matter of checking if the back pointer points to the same layer.

Since there's an API involved, I'd suggest, just because it sounds like you're pushing around a lot of data and have already profiled it, that you focus on an interface which revolves around aggregates (layers, e.g.) rather than individual elements (neurons). It'll just leave you a lot of room to swap out underlying representations when your clients aren't performing operations at the individual scalar element-type interface.

With the O(1) `contains` implementation and the unordered requirement, I'd go with a simple contiguous structure like `std::vector`. However, you do expose yourself to potential invalidation on insertion.

Because of that, if you can, I'd suggest working with indices here. However, that become a little unwieldy since it requires your clients to store both a pointer to the layer in which a neuron belongs in addition to its index (though if you do this, the backpointer becomes unnecessary as the client is tracking where things belong).

One way to mitigate this is to simply use something like `std::vector<Neuron*>` or `ptr_vector` if available. However, that can expose you to cache misses and heap overhead, and if you want to optimize that, this is where the fixed allocator comes in handy. However, that's a bit of a pain with alignment issues and a bit of a research topic, and so far it seems like your main goal is not to optimize insertion or sequential access quite as much as this `contains` check, so I'd start with the `std::vector<Neuron*>`.

Comment: I "own" the source, so I can easily implement that and hide it behind a common API. However, I was under the impression that I lose that flag once I do something like `*myIterator = someOtherNeuron`. I'd resort to a const iterator, but that would only allow me to access methods marked `const` on `Neuron`, wouldn't it...?

Comment: That somewhat depends on what copying means in this context. Normally a copy wouldn't necessarily belong in the same container, it'd be stranded on its own, so you don't necessarily want to copy the bits or the backpointers used to indicate what layers a fresh copy of a Neuron belongs to. A move constructor, on the other hand, is a different case -- and there you might be moving within the same container, so there you want to copy such data.

Comment: It gets a little fiddly if you want to mix in these kinds of STL constructs like iterators and allowing Neuron to be copyable/movable. For raw performance in these kinds of cases, it's somewhat handy to revert back to the less convenient constructs of C -- mainly because the majority of the STL was designed around non-intrusive containers that are completely decoupled from the elements they store. Here by coupling the two, you lose a lot of the generality, but it's hard to beat the performance of a constant-time (or close) check on neurons themselves to see if they belong in a set.

Comment: If performance is your need, I'd focus on making Neuron noncopyable and nonmovable to make it simpler, and focus on cloning and such through the aggregate interface (through your `Layer` API). It's somewhat like efficient particle systems -- there you don't typically have high-level/convenient constructs at the particle level. There it's just raw access to data typically, and the management of particles is driven through the container (the emitter). It's mainly because it's too difficult to decouple the two at an interface level if they're tightly coupled at the representation level.

Comment: Ok, that gives me some pointers. Noncopyable/nonmovable basically means something like `Neuron(const Neuron &) = delete; Neuron(Neuron &&) = delete;`?

Comment: Yep -- it's going to limit convenience a lot if you turn your `Neuron` interface into something lower-level like this, but it'll let you focus all the logic on some aggregate interface, like `Layer`. I'm not sure by your needs if Neurons can exist outside of any layer, but then you might have a master aggregate or a master layer from which you can transfer/copy one neuron to another layer, e.g., or if they can reside in multiple, simply insert the same neuron to another layer. By focusing on the aggregate interface, you leave yourself room for more backend optimizations that focus...

Comment: ... more on working with neurons in bulk. When you make each neuron into a high-level object that's copyable with lots of fancy logic in there, it's often hard to optimize past a certain point without breaking ABI (ex: SIMD optimizations). So it might be worth hiding the details of neurons outright (make them opaque) and forcing your clients to work with neurons through the layer interface or some other aggregate `master` interface kind of thing.

Comment: One critical thing that would help me a lot -- can a Neuron belong in more than one layer? And can it belong outside of any layer?

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for the whole lot of information! A Neuron is basically a low-level structure. It contains a (shared) pointer to an activation function and a small cache of recent inputs and calculation results, nothing more. Due to the latter, its position is unique, i.e., it can only be in one layer.

Comment: Update: I learned a lot from your answer and your comments. I've turned `Neuron` into a low-level data structure, and used `boost::ptr_vector`. Changing about 10 lines of code yielded an enormous performance boost. Thank you!

Comment: NP -- it's worth noting that `some_generic_container<T>` is generally going to be optimized a lot, but not to the extent where it can inject information into `T`. It can't intrude on `T`'s representation, so checking if `T` exists inside always involves a "search", even for a hash table. This is normally a wonderful thing as it allows those containers to work for anything at any given time, and most of the time productivity is more important than peak performance. But when peak performance is exactly what you need, you'll sometimes find the best solutions require changing `T` and having...

Comment: ... a container which understands exactly what `T` is. The next big step, if you want to go the distance, is often to start involving a custom fixed allocator for `T` which can allocate and deallocate `T` in O(1) and generally keep the memory contiguous for higher cache hits. That'll virtually eliminate much of the indirection/heap overhead. Feel free to hit me up again if you ever want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get O(1) contains-check, O(1) insert and preserve insertion order. If you are using Java, looked at LinkedHashMap. If you are not using Java, look at LinkedHashMap and figure out a parallel data structure that does it or implement it yourself.

It's just a hashmap with a doubly linked list. The link list is to preserve order and the hashmap is to allow O(1)  access. So when you insert an element, it makes an entry with the key, and the map will point to a node in the linked list where your data will reside. To look up, you go to the hash table to find the pointer directly to your linked list node (not the head), and get the value in O(1). To access them sequentially, you just traverse the linked list.

Comment: After reading your comment, I discovered `boost::multi_index_container`. Thanks for the hint; however, I've already travelled down the road of making the `Neuron` class noncopyable and nonmovable. :)

Comment: I re-read your question. Looks like you already had the idea. "Another idea was to use two data structures in the Layer object: A vector/list for the order, and a map/hash for lookup" But I don't understand your question, "But that would contradict my wish for an iterator that allowed operator* without a const reference, wouldn't it?"

Answer (score 0):

A heap sounds like it could be useful to you. It's like a tree, but the newest element is always inserted at the top, and then works its way down based on its value, so there is a method to quickly check if it's there.

Otherwise, you could store a hash table (quick method to check if the neuron is contained in the table) with the key for the neuron, and values of: the neuron itself, and the timestep upon which the neuron was inserted (to check its chronological insertion time).

Comment: Providing it's fast to hash the neuron for the second suggestion.